# Coordinate Geometry Question

Tags: geometry

given a parallelogram with points: 
O:(0,0) P(K,0) Q:(4,2) R:(x,y).
The equation of the line which passes through point O and point R is y=2x.

Find the all the co-ordinates?

I tried the question two different ways and got x=1 y=2 but for k I got two different value one was -3 and another was 3. I don't know which one is right
Here are the ways I did it:
way 1:

(0,0) to (4,2) is +4 on the x and +2 on the y

therefore (k,0) +4 on the x and +2 on y on the y gives (k+4,2)

x=k+4

using the equation I subbed 2 for y

y=2x

2=2(k+4)

1=k+4

k=-3

x=k+4

x=1

Way 2:

(0,0) to (k,0) is +k on the x

(x,y) to (4,2) +k on the x is x+k=4 and y=2

x=4-k

2=2(4-k)

4-k=1

k=3

x=1

Can someone please verify my answers and tell me which value for k is correct.

Comment: The difference between your answers should be the order of the points along the perimeter of the parallelogram.  If you want the order $O$, $P$, $Q$, $R$, then I think that your second way is better.  (But I didn't rigorously check, but the idea looks right).

Answer (score 0):

You have found two sets of answers. Both of them are numerically correct.

I have uploaded a picture to help you to determine whether you answer is correct or not.

[image]

However, from the fact that you are asking “which one is right”, I think you have missed the question – “Find the **all the (possible)** co-ordinates”.